# JavaScript wont show when non-admin log in but Administrator can

Tags: javascript

I added JavaScript to default.master in "http://localhost/_catalogs/masterpage/" via SPD 2007.the reason was for showing Date in every pages. I put this script on top page: `find "showdate()"`.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height=100% class="ms-globalright">
          <tr>
                  <td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:6px;">
                  <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink0"/>
                  </td>
              <td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks">
                <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                </wssuc:Welcome>
              </td>
              <td style="padding-left:1px;padding-right:3px;" class="ms-globallinks">|</td>
                  <td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                     <tr>
                      <td class="ms-globallinks">
                        <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink1" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>
                      <td class="ms-globallinks">
                        <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" Scope="Farm" runat="server"/></td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                  <td valign="middle" class="ms-globallinks">&nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:TopHelpButtonClick('NavBarHelpHome')" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplink_accesskey%>" id="TopHelpLink" title="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server">
                    <img align='absmiddle' border=0 src="http://sp2007/_layouts/images/helpicon.gif" alt="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_helplinkalt_text%>" runat="server"></a>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <p style="text-align:center ; font-size:11px ; font-family:Tahoma"><script>showdate()</script></p>
                </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
```

The problem is when I log in with administrator I can see them on page but with non-admin I can't see the date on the Welcome page. Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the page in?

Comment: yes i checked.just look at image.if user (non-admin) log into welcome page ,he wont see any date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the master page is checked in, published as a major version and approved. This is the exact behavior when that has not happened, things not working for users whereas it is fine for admins.

Comment: thanks you so much,it's Fixed.
What did i do ?
in SPD 
1) go Default.master in http://localhost/_catalogs/masterpage/ 
2) right click mouse then choose check in .
3) a message pop out and then choose "Publish as major Version" this will bring IE to you 
4) find default.master on page then left mouse click and choose "Publish a Major Version"
5) Choose "Approved. This item will become visible to all users."
6) done.